# Rebus #3 is pretty simple

Tags: rebus

No, this has zero to do with the sound you make when something's tasty...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would it be .....

> forms? four Ms.

Comment: OH MAN sniped by a second, well done! (+1)

Comment: @iiiidk: Good show!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's probably

> Forums (4 M's)

Comment: I just noticed this -- double sniped!! (+1 for you too!)

Answer (score 2):

Thinking the answer could be

> m&ms?

Comment: Good guess, but that would be "MnMMM."

Comment: @Wordster No, the answer is valid in my opinion: MMMM = M+MMM = M&Ms

Answer (score -1):

Is the answer (extra text)

> Forums?

Comment: EXACTLY! Had to add extra text...

Comment: Now we must see if it includes the U :^)

Comment: I think it's between you and Sconibulus in either case...good luck to both of you!